# Getting 404 when trying to clone mercurial repositories by script

Tags: bash, mercurial

This is one of the weirder issues I've experienced, and I can't tell if I'm experiencing a bash or an hg issue.

I have a list of hg repositories to clone (see BitBucket's EOL) and they're all in a file.

None of these work:

```
for url in `cat urls.txt`; do hg clone $url; done

cat urls.txt | xargs -n 1 hg clone

cat urls.txt | xargs -n 1 echo hg clone > clone.sh
sh clone.sh
. clone.sh
`cat clone.sh`
```

All of these merely yield `abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found` for every clone command.

This works:

```
cat clone.sh

[select output]
[copy]
[paste]
[enter]
```

The `clone.sh` file contains exactly what is expected; a lot of lines in the form `hg clone https://bitbucket/...`

I'm completely confused how a file with commands can yield one result when its contents are pasted directly into the shell, but a completely different result when run as a script (even with `.`, which executes it in the current shell instead of launching a new one). What is going on here?

Comment: Include `urls.txt` (the first 20 lines perhaps) in the question. `hg clone $url` may fail because of `bash` eating up or misinterpreting characters in `$url`. Always do `"$url"` in those scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: The urls.txt file contained CRLF line separators, having been generated on a Windows machine. For some reason, neither the shell nor hg nor the bitbucket.org server stripped this extraneous carriage return from the end of the URL, and it resulted in a 404 error.

Copying and pasting these normalized them to LF line separators. The same results were achieved when copying and pasting the contents of the script into a second script file - this then ran successfully.

Comment: `dos2unix urls.txt` can come in handy if you get file regenerated on Windows - and always do `"$url"` even if it happened to work without it this time. It wouldn't have worked if the url:s had `&` in them etc.